# UpdateActivity and DeleteActivity don't work when using Microsoft Teams iOS client

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have code, that should change adaptive card (delete of update) and it works correctly in Desktop app and Andriod also:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SendActivity(DialogContext outerDc,
                                                  IActivity activity,
                                                  bool replace,
                                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken){
    if (replace && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outerDc.Context.Activity.ReplyToId))
    {
        if (outerDc.Context.Activity.Type == activity.Type)
        {
            activity.Id = outerDc.Context.Activity.ReplyToId;
            await outerDc.Context.UpdateActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            await outerDc.Context.DeleteActivityAsync(outerDc.Context.Activity.ReplyToId, cancellationToken);
            await outerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await outerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
    }

    return await outerDc.EndDialogAsync();
}
```

but when call the same action from iOS client get an error

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
   
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.<DeleteActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.<DeleteActivityAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   ...
```

How to implement this for iOS correctly?

Answer (score 1):

@Mikhail, This is know issue in iOS. This is getting fixed and fix will be available soon.

Comment: Get the same issue, any ideas when it will be fixed?

Comment: We don't have ETA to share when it will be fixed.